# Quickly converting a string in the format of '0 1 1 0 1' into a bitset

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, bitset, std-bitset

How can I quickly convert a string of ones and zeroes separated by spaces into a `bitset`?

There exists a constructor to initialize a `bitset` from a string not separated by spaces, one to initialize a `bitset` to all zeroes or ones, and one to initialize from an integer. **Off the top of my head, I can think of three ways:**

- Removing the spaces from the string and passing it to the constructor
- Converting the binary into an integer and passing it to the constructor
- Initializing all values to zero and changing the value of each bit according to the string in a for-loop

The number of bits is 24, and each string has exactly 24 bits, no more, no less.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/d88f2709c095c75dc2cbef66cbe238da)'s the code I use to test performance, and [here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/b41a77e3cd993b58264e6a2785318d41)'s the code for methods one and two. On my machine, method 1 takes 3 ms, and method 3 takes 14 ms.

**EDIT 2:** I use `-O3 -o -g --std=c++11` are my compiler settings. I used gcc *and* clang.

Comment: I'd go with the 1st option.

Comment: I'd just remove all the spaces, go with option 1.

Comment: I'm still looking for methods other than the mentioned three. In my testing, method 1 is 4.67x faster than method 3

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC You're testing an optimized, release build, right?  And hopefully you're removing the spaces by `yourstring.erase(std::remove_if(yourstring.begin(), yourstring.end(), ::isspace), yourstring.end());`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Optimized debug build, yes I'm using that method

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC What is an "optimized debug build"?  What are the exact compiler options you're using when you built your application?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Update: on a 100% production build (gcc and clang somehow) I get 17.33% faster for method 1

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I'm still looking for the compiler options you used.  You should have `-O2` or `-O3` as a command-line option when building.  Otherwise, you're running an unoptimized build, and those times you're giving us are meaningless.  Please don't let this post devolve into one where we find out "yeah, now my times are much faster once I use those options".  A lot of persons helping on SO wind up wasting their time when things like this happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `-O3 -o -g --std=c++11`

Comment: ok.  That should always accompany a post when it comes to timing and performance.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Option 1 is slower than Dieter's implementation.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad, because there are an unbounded number of different answers. Mostly optimization of a computation involves using pre-established knowledge and constraints. The variations are endless (e.g. they include a table of character pairs with resulting bits).

Answer (score 1):

A conversion (not mutating the input string) to unsigned integer by setting each bit accordingly:

```
#include <bitset>
constexpr unsigned long long
extract_bits(const char* ptr, unsigned long long accumulator) {
    return (*ptr == 0)
        ? accumulator
        : extract_bits(ptr + 1, (*ptr == '1')
            ? accumulator << 1u | 1u
            : (*ptr == '0')
                ? accumulator << 1
                : accumulator);
}

template <unsigned N>
constexpr std::bitset<N>
to_bitset(const char* ptr) {
    return std::bitset<N>(extract_bits(ptr, 0));
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    constexpr auto b = to_bitset<24>("0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0");
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Note: The conversion ignores any character besides '0' and '1' quietly (A string like "01-01" is valid, too).

Getting timings for above conversion and erasing spaces from a string with:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std::chrono;

void print_duration(const char* what, const system_clock::time_point& start, const system_clock::time_point& stop) {
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << what << ": " << duration.count() << std::endl;
}

volatile unsigned long long result;
int main()
{
    std::string str = "0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0";
    std::vector<std::string> strings(1000, str);
    std::random_device random_device;
    std::mt19937 random_generator(random_device());
    for(auto& str : strings) {
        std::shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), random_generator);
    }

    // Non mutating to_bitset
    {
        auto start = system_clock::now();
        for(const auto& str : strings) {
            auto b = to_bitset<24>(str.c_str());
            result = b.to_ullong();
        }
        auto stop = system_clock::now();
        print_duration("to_bitset", start, stop);
    }
    // Erasing spaces
    {
        auto start = system_clock::now();
        for(auto& str : strings) {
            str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace), str.end());
            auto b = std::bitset<24>(str);
            result = b.to_ullong();
        }
        auto stop = system_clock::now();
        print_duration("str.erase", start, stop);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

g++ 4.8.4 with g++ -std=c++11 -O3 shows:

`to_bitset` is about 3 times faster than `erasing spaces from a string/constructing a bitset`.

Comment: the question is how fast

Comment: Why not time it and see?  Also, I highly doubt there is anything to gain by trying to micro-optimize removing 24 spaces from a string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not if you're running it in a loop millions of times

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC So maybe you should fix the issue further upstream, i.e., why does your string contain spaces?  Who / what put the spaces there?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Input for online course/online programming competition

Comment: This appears to be faster than method 1 by 2-3x with my compiler settings in the question

Comment: because you beat option 1 +1